# ¿Se puede usar varios request en un mutators de laravel 5.3?

Tags: php, laravel, laravel-5, model, dataset

Intento guardar en base de datos dos input que recibo y estaba pensando en hacerlo con mutators, la cuestión es que si modifico un campo solo manejo ese valor porque el $value que recibo es el que envia el request, pero necesito utilizar algo asi:

```
public function SetCedulaAttribute($value){
    //Se puede recibir un request? O un input que envia el controlador y que no esta en base de datos?
    $otroRequest = $request->nacion; 
    return $this->attributes['cedula'] = $otroRequest,'-'.$value;
}
```

Como hago para usar un input en un mutators? es posible?

Comment: La respuesta la tengo clara, sin embargo me gustaría saber un poco más del contexto, o en otras palabras, del código que almacena el atributo y como se están recibiendo los datos del request.

Comment: Ok, lo estoy enviando desde el formulario, dos campos recibe el controlador con el metodo store a traves de un request el cual estoy validando solo uno de los campos,  luego recibe el modelo y alli es el detalle, quiero saber si puedo manejar los dos input, si es posible. Se que tengo varias alternativas pero me surgio la duda.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

No es posible utilizar dos valores con un mutator, pues este acepta solo un valor en sus parámetros, o por lo menos no fue diseñado para eso, aunque podrían pasarse los valores como un objeto, array, json o similar:

```
/**
 * Set a given attribute on the model.
 *
 * @param  string  $key
 * @param  mixed  $value
 * @return $this
 */
public function setAttribute($key, $value)
{
    // First we will check for the presence of a mutator for the set operation
    // which simply lets the developers tweak the attribute as it is set on
    // the model, such as "json_encoding" an listing of data for storage.
    if ($this->hasSetMutator($key)) {
        $method = 'set'.Str::studly($key).'Attribute';

        return $this->{$method}($value);
    }

    // If an attribute is listed as a "date", we'll convert it from a DateTime
    // instance into a form proper for storage on the database tables using
    // the connection grammar's date format. We will auto set the values.
    elseif ($value && $this->isDateAttribute($key)) {
        $value = $this->fromDateTime($value);
    }

    if ($this->isJsonCastable($key) && ! is_null($value)) {
        $value = $this->castAttributeAsJson($key, $value);
    }

    // If this attribute contains a JSON ->, we'll set the proper value in the
    // attribute's underlying array. This takes care of properly nesting an
    // attribute in the array's value in the case of deeply nested items.
    if (Str::contains($key, '->')) {
        return $this->fillJsonAttribute($key, $value);
    }

    $this->attributes[$key] = $value;

    return $this;
}
```

Podrías intentar jugar con el facade Request para agregar el otro valor y poner un valor por defecto (en caso que no exista dicha llave en el Parameter bag), algo similar a lo que intentas:

```
$otroRequest = Request::get('nacion', 'ninguna');

return $this->attributes['cedula'] = $otroRequest,'-'.$value;
```

Comment: Entendido @shaz, probabre, imagine esa respuesta gracias por aclarar.

Comment: Hice lo de dos valores a traves de un array, pero el problema es cuando usas un request validator, entonces no se adapto a mi necesidad, pero gracias por la respuesta.

Comment: Por eso te decía que tocaría mirar mejor el contexto, infortunadamente los mutators no fueron diseñados para eso y hay que utilizar algún otro método para lograrlo.

Comment: Si, estoy en ello, ya estoy en otros metodos para lograrlo, hay diversos cualquier cosa pego un grito. Hay que intentar pensar por uno mismo jajaja Agradecido @Shaz!